# Is this Bayesian?

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I can't tell if I'm calculating this properly, I don't think it's a Bayesian question but I'm new to it so I'm not too sure.

> I have a sample of 30 people. Out of the 30, 90% do not use heroin (so 10% do). Those who do heroin, do it two days a week. If I were to as someone randomly whether they do heroin, what would be the probability that that person did it the day before?

This is what I did. So (30*.1)=3 people do it. The chance of those 1 of those people doing heroin during the week is (2/7) so for all 3 people it'd be (6/7).

But after that I'm stumped. Could someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: When editing your question to accord with the guidelines gung linked, please also fix the typo in your quoted section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conditional probability question. 
The formula for conditional probability is

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

You are looking at the probability of two events: whether a person does heroin (call this $P(B)$) and the probability someone does heroin on any given day (call this $P(A)$).

$P(A)$ is what you are looking for, but note that here $P(A\cap B)$ is the same as $P(A)$ because only people who do heroin have a probability of using it on any given day. [for the rest of the population that does not do heroin, you can call them $B^c$, or $B$ complement. $P(A\cap B^c)=0$. You can check that $P(A) = P(A\cap B) +P(A\cap B^c)$]

The information you gave is $P(B)$=1/10 and $P(A | B) = 2/7$.
You can plug this back into the formula to get your answer.